# Comment traduire « That screams X »

Tags: expressions, langage-informel

“Wow, that screams ‘France.’”

“That screams ‘Oh, I’m better than you.’”

En gros on parle d’un moyen pour dire que c’est tout à fait pareil à ce dont on parle. C’est complètement comme cet objet, ce genre de truc, etc.

Comment on dit ça en français ?

Answer (score 12):

One way to say it can be *tout craché* (like in *spitting image*):

> *C'est la France tout craché.* (possibly: *C'est la France toute crachée*)
>
> *C'est du « Oh, je suis mieux que toi » tout craché.*

Some alternatives are:

> *C'est exactement xxx.* (e.g. *la France*)
>
> *Ça sent xxx à plein nez.* (e.g. *la France*)
>
> *C'est typiquement xxx.* (e.g. *français*)

Keeping the "scream" idea:

> *C'est criant de ressemblance.*

See [Why the need to place "du" in the phase "Du Lowell tout craché"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19789/why-the-need-to-place-du-in-the-phase-du-lowell-tout-crach%c3%a9)

Comment: "Typiquement" pourrait aussi être employé

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, j'ai d'abord hésité mais je l'ajoute.

Answer (score 3):

En l'absence de contexte plus détaillé, j'y vais de mes deux suggestions :

- Ça me fait trop penser à la France!
- Ça fait vraiment le mec/la nana genre "je vaux mieux que les autres"!

Answer (score 0):

J'ai eu le bénéfice de lire les autres réponses. Il est inutile de reproduire la formulation avec le discours rapporté entre guillemets, peu authentique/inhabituel en français dans ce contexte à mon avis :

> *That screams ‘Oh, I’m better than you.’*
>  Ça (le comportement, les
>   propos, ce que tu viens de dire etc.) illustre/démontre/montre/dénote
>   franchement un air de supériorité.
>
> *Wow, that screams ‘France.’*
>  C'est très (voire qqch. de plus fort, comme *totalement/complètement/intimement*) représentatif
>   (de)/relié (à)/associé (à) la France.
>  C'est la France dans/en
>   (une seule) [chose à laquelle on réfère].

D'accord c'est plutôt informel en anglais ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scream)). En consultant d'autres [exemples](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/scream), je suis d'avis qu'il n'existe aucune formulation uniforme capable de tous les traduire. Par exemple :

> *That big white dress screams “Marry me.”*
>  Cette grande robe blanche-là c'est (quasiment comme) ou évoque (avec un adverbe pour un haut degré) une demande en mariage.
>   Faut vouloir se marier pour porter une grande robe blanche comme ça.
>
> *The amount she paid in taxes was so low that it practically screamed “fraud.”*
>  Elle avait si peu payé d'impôts que ça suggérait/trahissait
>   presque (en soi, par le fait même) qu'il s'agissait d'une fraude.

C'est soit « qui indique très clairement » ou « suggère spontanément ». N'importe quelle formulation idiomatique dont la sémantique s'en approche fonctionne à mon avis.